# Close Case button missing from Lightning

Tags: case, lightning, button, community

After changing sharing settings for Cases and couple other objects to Private, i can't see "Close Case" button, but only in lightning/community.
In classic it's where it should be.
I'm doing all this on standard administrator profile, with some permission sets.
I also have custom object lookup on cases, but i have access to all of its fields etc.

Any idea what would cause this?

Comment: I also enabled Knowledge(Articles) prior to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard "Close Case" button is not supported in Lightning. 
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cMWbQAM